# is there a way to remove qoutes " in csv but also include semicolon after exporting?

Tags: php, csv, export, export-to-csv

I know that for any of the languages for example php, if I am exporting data into csv file and if data contains the delimiter such as ; or , I need to wrap the data with ""

For example if my data is `Hello, World` after csv is exported `Hello` and `World` will not be in the same column and instead different.  By solving this issue I know lots posts are saying wrap with `"`which will then be `"Hello, World"` then the output in csv will be "`"Hello, World"` which is within the same row and column BUT the qoutes `"` will also be in the csv file

Having this image as example:

[image]

row 2 is pretty much what is needed BUT it has qoutes too after exporting.  My question is, is there is way to get ride of the qoutes BUT also keep the delimeter such as comma or semicolon in place?

Thanks in advance for any help / advices

Comment: And without those quotes, how is any reader to know that something like `Hello, World, Testing` contains two columns: `Hello, World` and `Testing`, and not three columns: `Hello`, `World` and `Testing`?

Comment: please add to your question an example output. 

In a CSV if you have the field separator inside a cell, you will have quotes for that cell. It's a rule. TSV output could be your solution